# Dropzone.js uploads only two files when autoProcessQueue set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I use [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com) and I want it to upload the dropped not automatically but when the user clicks a button. So I set the `autoProcessQueue` option to `false`. When the button is clicked the `processQueue()` method is called. I would suppose that now the full queue is processed. But thats not the case. Only the number of files which is specified in the `parallelUploads` option will be uploaded. The standard value of `parallelUploads` seems to be 2. Which every click 2 files are processed and uploaded.

Do I have to set `parallelUploads` to an very high number, for now to solve this?

Here's my full JS code:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", {
  url: "http://www.torrentplease.com/dropzone.php",
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  thumbnailWidth: "80",
  thumbnailHeight: "80",
  dictCancelUpload: "Cancel",
  autoProcessQueue: false
});

myDropzone.on("drop", function(event) {
  $('.edit_tooltip .option_bar').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: "-5"
  });
});


$('.edit_tooltip .option_bar .button').click(function() {
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Comment: This is because `parallelUploads` defaults to 2 if not set in your options.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's a simple way to solve this which can be found here:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/253#issuecomment-22184190

"If you want autoProcessQueue to be true after the first upload, then just listen to the processing event, and set this.options.autoProcessQueue = true; inside."

So just add

```
this.on("processing", function() {
    this.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
});
```

Comment: Because I was using this from an external process to start the upload, here's what my code looked like:

myDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;

I had the parraleleupload setting = 1, and this caused each file to upload 1 by 1. 

THANKS for the correct solution.

Comment: This indeed makes that the files are uploaded sequentially, but now the action url is called for each individual file! In my example, with this solution, I receive as many emails as files. and this is not what I want! I would like that the files are uploaded sequentially and only after that, the action url is called. is it possible?

Answer (score 57):

Add **parallelUploads: 10**(This is your max no)

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent half a day on solving this problem, and finally your answer helps me.

Comment: To be clear, this approach requires that the ```parallelUploads``` is set equal to or larger than ```maxFiles```, otherwise if a user drops more than ```paralleluploads``` files, the last few may not get uploaded.  Bianka's answer below seems more 'correct' in the sense that it allows ```parallelUploads``` to function independently of ```maxFiles```, in the way it was designed.

Comment: Not sure it's the best solution. Not if we want more than 10 files to be uploaded.

Answer (score 23):

My solution is:

```
// init dropzone with auto process queue false
var adPhotosDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    parallelUploads: 3
});

$(document).on('click', '#btnUpload', function () {
    // enable auto process queue after uploading started
    adPhotosDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
    // queue processing
    adPhotosDropzone.processQueue();
});

// disable queue auto processing on upload complete
adPhotosDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function() {
    adPhotosDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = false;
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, as I have an event that initiates the upload.  It seems that setting `autoProcessQueue=true` just before `processQueue()` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Very late but maybe it will help someone.

I noticed when I placed maxFilesSize above parallerUploads it didn't worked.

So sequence for options should be
.

```
.
.
parallelUploads: 20,    
maxFilesize: 2, 
maxFiles: 20,
.
.
```

Comment: maxFilesize is [the maximum filesize (in bytes) that is allowed to be uploade](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/configuration-options) .  It is not related to the topic here.

Answer (score 4):

Add overdrive two event like

processing -> Allow upload all file

queuecomplete -> Return to normal

```
    init: function () {

            this.on("queuecomplete", function () {
                this.options.autoProcessQueue = false;
            });

            this.on("processing", function () {
                this.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
            });

    };
```

Answer (score 3):

i used this dropzone with option (autoProcessQueue:false) and it does only upload 2 files instead of my whole files. And i found this workaround [in the oligoil's answer at the git's issue](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1122#issuecomment-396754723)

The Idea is very simple (bcs we want to upload the files one by one, remember the option! :D ).

It upload multiple but limited to 1, after one file is uploaded it trigger the next Queue!

Hope it help someone!

here's my code using that idea ( since i have 2 forms to upload, after all the images is uploaded it will submitting the other forms )

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks:true,
        parallelUploads : 1,
        maxFiles : 50,
        autoProcessQueue : false,
        autoQueue : true,
        dictDefaultMessage: "<strong>Drop files here or click to upload. </strong>",
        init: function () {
            ....

            this.on("complete", function (file) {
                if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                    console.log("END ", this.getQueuedFiles().length);
                }
                else {
                    Dropzone.forElement("#dropzoneForm").processQueue();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you dont want to set maxFiles (default no limit) and use parallelUploads with the value you want. Read this!**

I have solved the problem behaviour by setting

```
autoQueue: false,
autoProcessQueue: true,
```

Then when I want to upload the files I just add them to the queue with:

```
myDrop.enqueueFile(file)
```

But, this method just accept one file, for multiple files I'am using:

```
myDrop.on("addedfiles", function(files){
 //wait confirmation, or do some processing with the files, then:

 files.forEach(function(file){
    myDrop.enqueueFile(file)
 })
}
```

Note that "addedfiles" event it's not in the documentation yet. I captures all files dragged into the dropzone or added by the click event.

This is good because if you are using "sending" event to add POST data, or "parallelUploads" the sample code works fine and don't mess with the next files. I am using Sweet Alert 2 to ask for some tags before uploading the images.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can allow uploadMultiple and change dropzone.js file.

First, allow uploadMultiple
Next,  change this line code into dropzone.js:

> return this.processFiles(queuedFiles.slice(0, parallelUploads - processingLength));

for

> return this.processFiles(queuedFiles.slice(0, queuedFiles.length));

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I wasn't happy with the other answers, so here's mine.

Changing autoProcessingQueue (even temporarily) after clicking send mean that if you add another file to the dropzone while other are still queued, it will get uploaded without you having to press send again, which I didn't want. And I didn't want to use a setTimeout or a busyloop either. So here's how to do it without either :

Modify the dropzone.js file. First, in the Dropzone function, you need to add a second file array to store the queue when send is pressed :

```
function Dropzone(element, options) {
  ...
  this.files = [];
  this.files2 = [];
```

Then, save the files to it when send is clicked by modifying processQueue

```
Dropzone.prototype.processQueue = function() {
  this.files2 = this.getQueuedFiles();
  ...
```

Finally, edit the _finished function so that when a file is done uploading, another file get sent if there was still remaining ones in the queue when send was pressed:

```
Dropzone.prototype._finished = function(files, responseText, e) {
  var file, _i, _len;
  for (_i = 0, _len = files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    file = files[_i];
    file.status = Dropzone.SUCCESS;
    this.emit("success", file, responseText, e);
    this.emit("complete", file);
    this.files2 = this.files2.filter(function(e) { return e.status == "queued" }); // Remove the files that are finished or already being uploaded
  }
  if (this.options.uploadMultiple) {
    this.emit("successmultiple", files, responseText, e);
    this.emit("completemultiple", files);
  }
  if (this.options.autoProcessQueue) {
    return this.processQueue();
  }
  else {
      if (typeof this.files2 != "undefined" && this.files2.length > 0) {
          this.processFiles(this.files2.slice(0,1)); // process the next file if there's one
      }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This solved it for me, without changing any dropzone.js code or voiding the parallelUploads setting.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  function tryQueue(){
    var numQueued=dz.getQueuedFiles().length;
    var numFiles=numQueued+dz.getUploadingFiles().length;
    if(numQueued>0){
      dz.processQueue();
    }
    if(numFiles>0){
      setTimeout(tryQueue,1000);
    }
    else window.location='/'; //redirect when finished
  }
  tryQueue();
});
```

This assumes that dz is the dropzone instance. It works by invoking processQueue until all have been uploaded. The logic in processQueue takes care of returning if nothing needs to be done so no harm in the polling.